# Как переделать код что бы класс active применялся не к li а к самой a ссылке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как переделать скрипт чтобы класс **active** применялся не только к основным пунктам но и к подпунктам отдельно. Не могу понять как повесить класс active на класс **scroll-to**, а не на его родителя.

Сейчас класс active применяется к тегу li внутри меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и стили применяются ко всему тегу **li** и подпунктам 2.1 и 2.2 . Нужно чтобы класс **active** добавлялся только к ссылка с классом **scroll-to** внутри **li**. То естьи пункты и подпункты должны выделяться по очереди.

Вот код с примером. http://jsfiddle.net/MrRJDio/bp4Lq71a/

Понимаю что где-то в этом месте. Но как изменить не знаю.

```
menuItems
    .parent().removeClass("active")
    .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
```

```js
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
  topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
  topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
  // All list items
  menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
  // Anchors corresponding to menu items
  scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) {
      return item;
    }
  });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e) {
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight + 1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Get container scroll position
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

  // Get id of current scroll item
  var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
      return this;
  });
  // Get the id of the current element
  cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
  var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

  if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
    // Set/remove active class
    menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("active")
      .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 6000px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

#top-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#top-menu li {
  float: left;
}

#top-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
  transition: .5s all ease-out;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#top-menu li.active a {
  border-top: 3px solid #333;
  color: #333;
}

#foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}

#bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 800px;
}

#baz {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#">Top</a>
    <ol class="articleSubList">
      <li class="article-item"><a class="scroll-to" href="#header2.1">2.1</a></li>
      <li class="article-item"><a class="scroll-to" href="#header2.2">2.2</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a id="foo">Foo</a>


<a id="bar">Bar</a>


<a id="baz">Baz</a>
```

Comment: непонятно что именно сейчас не работает. Добавь больше описания

Comment: Добавил картинку. Сейчас класс active применяется к тегу li внутри меню и стили применяются ко всему тегу **li** и подпунктам 2.1 и 2.2 . Нужно чтобы класс **active** добавлялся только к ссылка с классом **scroll-to** внутри **li**. То естьи пункты и подпункты должны выделяться по очереди.

Comment: Просто нужен скрипт который будет подсвечивать пункты и подпункты меню когда к ним доскролил. Но почему-то все, что я находил не работают корректно.

Comment: достаточно поменять стиль `li.active a` на `li.active > a`

Comment: плюс поправить место где выбирается какой пункт меню активен

Comment: Теперь проблема с тем ,что на подпункты 2.1 и 2.2  не вешается класс active когда до них доскроливаешь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109898/discussion-between-grundy-and-dio).